# Bot implemented using Composer - Save conversation history to PostGresql or other custom database

Tags: botframework, storage

We have implemented a bot using Microsoft Composer. We would like to store the conversation history to a PostGreSql database.

I have checked the links : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-custom-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
But they work for SDK first Bots and they don't seem to work for Adaptive dialogs implemented using Composer.
Any help is greatly appreciated